# $http not defined in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am facing a problem with below code. It showing $http undefined in console. I have injected $scope and $http as well

```
SignInCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
function SignInCtrl($scope,$http) {
$scope.login = function($http) {   
return $http.post('/user/login', user).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error creating user'));

};
}
```

Comment: remove the $http parameter from function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
$scope.login = function($http)
```

by

```
$scope.login = function()
```

The caller doesn't pass the $http service as argument. It's injected in the controller. So your function declaration hides the injected $http by the (undefined) one (not) passed as argument.

Answer (score -1):

```
/**@inject*/
function SignInCtrl($scope,$http) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        return $http.post('/user/login', user).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error creating user'));
    };
}
```

using /** @ngInject */ u can inject all dependencies you don't have to write all dependencies like (SignInCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http']);

In $scope.login function you are passing $http which is not required you have injected already

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.